# How to setup oddslib js library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use this odds lib library I have found with this link:

https://github.com/1player/oddslib

However, I notice when I import it, I get a warning.

Did I setup the oddslib correctly? I did do an `npm install oddslib`

The reason I ask is because when I hover over that import (`import * as oddslib from "oddslib";`), it states:

```
module "c:xxx/Desktop/cypress-cucumber/node_modules/oddslib/dist/oddslib.cjs"
Could not find a declaration file for module 'oddslib'. 'c:/xxx/Desktop/cypress-cucumber/node_modules/oddslib/dist/oddslib.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/oddslib` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'oddslib';`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems like you are using Typescript with an unsupported library which does not directly support Typescript nor has a separate type declaration package.

However it does not mean that you can't use it! You can use it but without any typing feature that Typescript brings.

You can ignore it or write [declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) yourself.

Also you might want to install package with `--save` option to add them automatically to your `package.json` file:

```
npm install --save oddslib
```